# python3.5 import tensorflow.contrib error: Function has keyword-only arguments or annotations, use getfullargspec() API which can support them

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow, anaconda, inspect

I am using python 3.5 and installed tensorflow-gpu 1.12.0 on Linux. When I run this in python3.5:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

It works fine with no errors.

However, when I run:

```
import tensorflow.contrib
```

There is an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import distributions
File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distributions/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
from tensorflow.contrib.distributions.python.ops.estimator import *
     File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/distributions/python/ops/estimator.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.head import _compute_weighted_loss
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/__init__.py", line 96, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import estimators
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/__init__.py", line 302, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.dnn import DNNClassifier
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py", line 35, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import dnn_linear_combined
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import estimator
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io import data_feeder
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io.dask_io import extract_dask_data
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/dask_io.py", line 33, in <module>
    import dask.dataframe as dd
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .core import (DataFrame, Series, Index, _Frame, map_partitions,
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .. import array as da
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/array/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .core import (Array, stack, concatenate, take, tensordot, transpose,
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/array/core.py", line 13, in <module>
    from toolz.curried import (pipe, partition, concat, unique, pluck, join, first,
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/toolz/curried/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    _curry_namespace(vars(toolz)),
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/toolz/curried/__init__.py", line 48, in _curry_namespace
    for name, f in ns.items() if '__' not in name
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/toolz/curried/__init__.py", line 48, in <genexpr>
    for name, f in ns.items() if '__' not in name
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/toolz/curried/__init__.py", line 42, in _should_curry
    return (callable(f) and _nargs(f) > 1 or f in do_curry)
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/toolz/curried/__init__.py", line 35, in _nargs
    return len(inspect.getargspec(f).args)
  File "/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/inspect.py", line 1050, in getargspec
    raise ValueError("Function has keyword-only arguments or annotations"
ValueError: Function has keyword-only arguments or annotations, use getfullargspec() API which can support them
```

I searched for getfullargspec() API but got even more confused. As far as I know, the getfullargspec() API from inspect can only do with something like

```
getfullargsspec(function_name)
```

How can I do with it? I could appreciate it a lot if you could explain the cause and also possibly a simple solution.

---

Plus, I am running the code on a remote server without root permission. Command lines such as
**sudo** xxxxx
do not work for me.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I also face this problem. I found this way to solve this problem.

```
conda install toolz
```

Good Luck